# duplicate chrome tab & executing a jquery code based on document.ready event

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

i have a big div tag that is centered in the middle of the screen using jquery
so far everything is perfect !
but i've noticed a big problem
when i right click on the current tab, and select 'duplicate tab' i get a new one .. but the div tag is not really centered, so i have this theory :
since my tag is centered based on a document.ready event .. so the div is centered only after loading the whole page .. witch is not the case when i duplicate the tab .. chrome doesn't reload it .. it just clones it without reloading it
and then the div get to the left and not centered and looks awful and the half of it is not displayed !
any way to fix this bug ? should i duplicate the same jquery code but with another event .. other than document.ready ?
big thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Please format your question so it's readable

Comment: what didn't you understand in my question ?